# Why is python 3.7 replaced by python 3.8 when using pipenv in github actions?

Tags: python, github, github-actions, pipenv

I have found something really strange in github actions.

I am using github actions to test my python scripts automatically for python 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9 with pipenv.
Then, I have found python 3.8 is used to create a virtual environment with pipenv after setupping python 3.7.

I don't know why.

Do you have any idea?
Please tell me to use python **3.7** to create a vritual environment with pipenv in github actions.

Details are follows.

## Workflow yaml

```yaml
name: PyVersion

on: [ workflow_dispatch ]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.7, 3.8, 3.9]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - name: Check python version
        run: |
          python -V
      - name: Install requirements
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install pipenv
      - name: create a virtual environment
        run: |
          pipenv install
      - name: Check Pipfile
        run: |
          cat Pipfile
      - name: delete the virtual environment
        run: |
          pipenv --rm
```

## Jobs Results for each steps

- For python 3.7 (**Unexpected Result**)

  - Set up Python 3.7: `Successfully setup CPython (3.7.11)`
  - Check python version: `Python 3.7.11`
  - Create a virtual environment:

    ```
    Creating a virtualenv for this project...
    Pipfile: /home/runner/work/github-actions-sandbox/github-actions-sandbox/Pipfile
    Using /usr/bin/python3.8 (3.8.10) to create virtualenv...
    created virtual environment CPython3.8.10.final.0-64 in 525ms
    ```
  - Check Pipfile:

    ```
    [[source]]
    url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
    verify_ssl = true
    name = "pypi"

    [packages]

    [dev-packages]

    [requires]
    python_version = "3.8"
    ```
- For python 3.8  (Expected Result)

  - Set up Python 3.8: `Successfully setup CPython (3.8.11)`
  - Check python version: `Python 3.8.11`
  - Create a virtual environment:

    ```
    Creating a virtualenv for this project...
    Pipfile: /home/runner/work/github-actions-sandbox/github-actions-sandbox/Pipfile
    Using /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.11/x64/bin/python3.8 (3.8.11) to create virtualenv...
    created virtual environment CPython3.8.11.final.0-64 in 661ms
    ```
  - Check Pipfile:

    ```
    [[source]]
    url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
    verify_ssl = true
    name = "pypi"

    [packages]

    [dev-packages]

    [requires]
    python_version = "3.8"
    ```
- For python 3.9 (Expected Result)

  - Set up Python 3.9: `Successfully setup CPython (3.9.6)`
  - Check python version: `Python 3.9.6`
  - Create a virtual environment:

    ```
    Creating a virtualenv for this project...
    Pipfile: /home/runner/work/github-actions-sandbox/github-actions-sandbox/Pipfile
    Using /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.6/x64/bin/python3.9 (3.9.6) to create virtualenv...
    created virtual environment CPython3.9.6.final.0-64 in 483ms
    ```
  - Check Pipfile:

    ```
    [[source]]
    url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
    verify_ssl = true
    name = "pypi"

    [packages]

    [dev-packages]

    [requires]
    python_version = "3.9"
    ```

Answer (score 0):

Please change task version to `v2`?

```
      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
```

Comment: Thank you for you advice!

Comment: Thank you for your advice!
But this happened in an empty repository, i.e. no Pipfile.

I expect that Pipfile is automatically created when calling `pipenv install` in a directory without Pipfile and requires.python_version in the Pipfile is set to be the version of python used.
However, another version of python, python 3.8,  is used to create Pipfile even though I specified python 3.7 in github actions.

Comment: Do you mean that `sed -i -e s/python_version = "3.8"/python_version = "3.7"/g Pipfile` works in workflow yaml for github actions?

Comment: Sorry, now I see your point. Could you update task version for setup-python?